# Jenkins server freezes while running jar

Tags: java, jenkins, jar, server

Basically in the file system that I used as source control for Jenkins only has an executable `.jar` with all of the necessary libraries packaged into it. The only other configuration I have on the job itself is a Windows command build step, `java -jar name.jar`. I am able to run this on Windows Command Prompt, but every time I try to build it on the master computer, the build does not complete and the `.jar` file does not execute.

I am running this build logged in as the admin of the server.